# Unlock all levels in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

I recently formatted my computer and Steam Cloud didn't save everything I did. How do I get my levels back?
Thanks.

Comment: 1) What operating system do you have. 2) How and with what did you format your computer?

Comment: I had moreless formatted my computer and more re installed Windows 8.1. Which is my OS.

Comment: Being a Windows 8 machine did you refresh / reset it or did you use a 3rd party program?

Comment: Nope, didn't use any third party programs.

Comment: So what did you use?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer would be to play them again but I assume that's not what you want.

Portal's saves are stored locally, in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\portal 2\portal2\SAVE . If you find a completed save file, you can copy it into that directory and load it. This will unlock everything.

Comment: Just wondering, if he formatted his PC can he still access his saves?

Comment: @sebie probably not unless he didnt format it properly or made a backup

Comment: Assuming he formatted the partition his Steam folders were on, he can't access his saves. There are programs for recovering files after formatting, but I believe that's beyond the scope of Arqade and the results may vary.

Comment: @Sebie No. Portal 2 saves are only stored locally and reformatting the hard drive erases everything. Unless OP had the foresight to backup his saves of course but then he wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @Taacoo ,@Chippies ,@Studoku . I understand that when you format a hard drive it wipes everything, but my experience with Windows restore has been positive, actually.

I formatted it to the core basics and I forgot to copy something and I could *still* restore back, to before I formatted it.

Comment: Hmm. I can't find any sort of completed save; I've tried the unlock all levels command in Half Life 2, but it won't work.

Comment: @Sebie That's true but dependent on OP's operating system and what he actually means by formatting. Since he didn't go into specifics, my answer assumes the data is lost forever. (If he did, it'd probably be more suited for SuperUser anyway).

Comment: @dre If you are looking for a way to cheat yourself the levels, it would be worthwhile taking a look at [this](http://www.cheatcc.com/pc/portal2cheatscodes.html) or [this](http://au.ign.com/cheats/games/portal-2-xbox-360-64330).

Comment: @Studoku If you want I can flag it as off-topic, otherwise I asked above about the system specs and method.